# What is $\mathbb Z^2/\text{Im}(\phi)$ isomorphic to in the following case?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

> Let $\phi:\mathbb Z^2\to\mathbb Z^2$ be the map $(x,y)\mapsto (x+y,2y)$. 
>   I need to find $\mathbb Z^2/\text{Im}(\phi)$.

My guess is that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2$ but I am having trouble proving it.

I tried defining a map $\psi:\mathbb Z^2\to \mathbb Z_2$ by $(x,y)\mapsto [x+y]$ and use the first isomorphism theorem however, the kernel of this map is $\{(2x-y,y):(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2\}$ which s not what I need. I can't find the required map. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(a,b) \in \operatorname{Im} \phi$ if and only if $b$ is even (If $b$ is even, we can choose $y=\frac{b}{2}$ and $x=a-y$). We deduce $\operatorname{Im} \phi = \mathbb Z \oplus 2\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$, hence the quotient is indeed $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Looking at your approach, the map you are searching is just $\mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,(x,y) \mapsto y$.

Comment: Very nice, beat me to it as I was editing my deleted answer. +1